# Using variables for unknown reserved keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to dynamically convert values to unknown saved data types, simple example:

```
DECLARE @Type nvarchar(max) = 'int'

SELECT CONVERT(@Type, '1234')
```

How can one achieve this?

Comment: Dynamic sql ? Otherwise, I don't think you can do that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way is to formulate a string and execute it

```
DECLARE @Type nvarchar(max) = 'int'

Exec('SELECT CONVERT(' + @Type + ', ''1234'')')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a CASE statement? These are all `INT` but it shows the thinking.....

```
DECLARE @Type nvarchar(max);
SET @Type = 'int';

SELECT CASE WHEN Upper(@Type)='INT' THEN CONVERT(int, '1234')
            WHEN Upper(@Type)='INT' THEN CONVERT(int, '1234')
            ELSE CONVERT(int, '1234') END;
```